# Angular - array forEach index

Tags: arrays, angular, foreach

How to identify the index for the `forEach` loop in the Angular4 code.

I need to splice the record inside the foreach based on the condition.

```
angular.forEach(myObject => {
    if(!myObject.Name)
        myObject.splice(..., 1)
};
```

Here I want to delete the object if the name in `myObject` is blank.

Comment: Is `myObject` an array?

Comment: yes, it is an array. And I got the answer from HDJEMAI below.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`forEach` is documented here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

**Syntax:**

> arr.forEach(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
> // execute something
> }[, thisArg]);

**Parameters:**

> **callback:**
> Function to execute on each element. It accepts between one and three arguments:

> **currentValue:** The current element being processed in the array.

> **index:** Optional,
> **The index of currentValue in the array.**

> **array:** Optional,
> The array forEach() was called upon.

> **thisArg:** Optional,
> Value to use as this when executing callback.

To be able to use an index inside this forEach loop, you can add an index this way:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular 6';
    myArray = [{name:"a"}, {name:""}, {name:"b"}, {name:"c"}];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.removeEmptyContent();
    }

    removeEmptyContent() {
        this.myArray.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
          if(!currentValue.name) {
              this.myArray.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

**Working Stackblitz demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-g1m1dz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: is angular.forEach the same as array.forEach?

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter of the function for loop index.

```
angular.forEach(myArray,function(arrayItem,index){
  console.log(arrayItem,index);
})
```